# Quick modulus q help

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that $|a| \leq b$ then $-b\leq a \leq b$?

Please help.

Comment: Clearly you missed something

Comment: Here I fixed it now. Look.

Comment: yes correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition either $a = |a|$ or $a = -|a|$.  In the first case you have $$ - b \le 0 \le a = |a| \le b$$ and in the second case you have $$b \ge 0 \ge a = -|a| \ge -b.$$ In both cases you have $$-b \le a \le b.$$

Comment: Say if I have $|f|\leq 1/R$ where $f$ is a function and $1/R$ is an upper bound for $f$. If $1/R$ tends to $0$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$ then does that mean since we have $-R\leq f \leq R$, by the sandwich rule, $|f| \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: You mean $-1/R \le f \le 1/R$, but the answer is yes. Even simpler is to apply the sandwich rule to $0 \le |f| \le 1/R$ directly.

Comment: yes that is what I meant. thanks